sonata admin event sonata.admin.event.configure.menu.sidebar not exist
here is code
root@dfdd65d13cfb:/application# composer show sonata-project/admin-bundle
name     : sonata-project/admin-bundle
descrip. : The missing Symfony Admin Generator
keywords : admin, admin-generator, admin-lte, bundle, sonata, symfony
versions : * 4.31.0
released : 2024-07-15, 2 months ago
type     : symfony-bundle
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
homepage : https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle
source   : [git] https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle.git 73492afdcdf6cb5314685b2661f87dc906b1f2b6
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/zipball/73492afdcdf6cb5314685b2661f87dc906b1f2b6 73492afdcdf6cb5314685b2661f87dc906b1f2b6
path     : /application/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle
names    : sonata-project/admin-bundle

support
issues : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues
source : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/tree/4.31.0

autoload
psr-4
Sonata\AdminBundle\ => src/

requires
doctrine/collections ^1.6 || ^2.0
doctrine/common ^3.0
ext-json *
knplabs/knp-menu ^3.1
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ^3.0
php ^8.0
psr/container ^1.0 || ^2.0
psr/log ^2.0 || ^3.0
sonata-project/block-bundle ^4.11 || ^5.0
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions ^1.8 || ^2.0
sonata-project/exporter ^2.14 || ^3.1.1
sonata-project/form-extensions ^1.15 || ^2.0
sonata-project/twig-extensions ^1.4.1 || ^2.0
symfony/asset ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/config ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/console ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/dependency-injection ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/doctrine-bridge ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/event-dispatcher ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts ^2.0 || ^3.0
symfony/expression-language ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/form ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/framework-bundle ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/http-foundation ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/http-kernel ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/options-resolver ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/property-access ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/routing ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/security-acl ^3.1
symfony/security-bundle ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/security-core ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/security-csrf ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/serializer ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/string ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/translation ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/translation-contracts ^2.3 || ^3.0
symfony/twig-bridge ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/twig-bundle ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/validator ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
twig/string-extra ^3.0
twig/twig ^3.0

requires (dev)
friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer ^3.4
matthiasnoback/symfony-config-test ^4.2 || ^5.0
matthiasnoback/symfony-dependency-injection-test ^4.2 || ^5.0
phpstan/extension-installer ^1.0
phpstan/phpstan ^1.0
phpstan/phpstan-phpunit ^1.0
phpstan/phpstan-strict-rules ^1.0
phpstan/phpstan-symfony ^1.0
phpunit/phpunit ^9.5
psalm/plugin-phpunit ^0.18
psalm/plugin-symfony ^5.0
psr/event-dispatcher ^1.0
rector/rector ^1.1
symfony/browser-kit ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/css-selector ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/filesystem ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/maker-bundle ^1.25
symfony/phpunit-bridge ^6.2 || ^7.0
symfony/yaml ^5.4 || ^6.2 || ^7.0
vimeo/psalm ^5.8.0

suggests
twig/extra-bundle Auto configures the Twig Intl extension
root@dfdd65d13cfb:/application# php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher | grep sonata
"sonata.block.event.sonata.admin.list.table.top" event

why this event not exist ?
https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataAdminBundle/en/4.x/cookbook/recipe_knp_menu/#extending-the-menu
